# an example to show separability of a Banach space does not imply separability of the dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

$X$ is a Banach space and it is separable, is there any simple counterexample to show the dual space $X^\ast$ is not separable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual of $\ell^1$ (clearly separable by finite sequences of rational numbers) is $\ell^\infty$ (clearly not separable, as you have $\mathfrak c$-many disjoint balls of radius $1/2$ around indicator functions).